# Upload large files in web api from react application. we are trywant to pass large file to web api from react client project with http client object

Tags: reactjs, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, large-data, large-files

File first comes in client API controller from js, then file converted to bytes and created JSON object after that this request we send to web API with the HTTP client. like this var response = await Client.PostAsJsonAsync(URL, request); in web API its saves in the database.
My issue is large file is taking too much time when they pass from client API to web AP

Comment: My issue is large file is taking too much time when they pass from client api to web API.
    Below is the request passes to web API from react is
    var request = new
    {
    DocData = bytes,
    Cid = applicationDocument.UserName,`enter code here`
    cust = 1,
    FileName = FileName
    };
    what is the correct approach of doing this?

Comment: Could you provide more info? What size of the "large file"? How much time does it take to pass? Do you have a reliable and quick internet connection? Why do you use JSON for that? Do you have a look at FormData(https://www.pluralsight.com/guides/how-to-use-a-simple-form-submit-with-files-in-react)?

Comment: Large file means 1o mb file, in front end project from js to controller its coming easily, but from client controller to web API , it's taking too much time.  what will be the good practice when we transfer big file from one api to other